# Why can't I catch the ServiceException on the Azure PHP sdk?

Tags: php, azure, blob

I'm trying to find out whether a blob exists or not. When the blob does not exist, my `try-catch` with Azure's `ServiceException` isn't being caught at all. I tried following the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297646/check-if-blob-exists-in-azure).

```
public function checkBlobExists($path) {

    $container = config('azure.storage.container');
    $blobClient = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService(config('azure.storage.connection_string'));

    try {

        $blob = $blobClient->getBlob($container, $path); 
        return true;

    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is some of the error stack:

```
ServiceException in ServiceRestProxy.php line 491:
Fail:
Code: 404
Value: The specified blob does not exist.
details (if any): .
in ServiceRestProxy.php line 491
at ServiceRestProxy::throwIfError(object(Response), array('200', '206')) in ServiceRestProxy.php line 409
at ServiceRestProxy->MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\{closure}(object(ClientException)) in Promise.php line 203
```

Comment: Off topic comment .... IMHO `getBlob` could be a very expensive operation for checking the existence of the blob as it downloads the blob. Why not use `getBlobProperties` which is much lightweight operation?

Comment: @GauravMantri I ended up using `getBlobProperties`. Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not be using the fully qualified exception class name. Try:

```
//...
} catch (\MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException $e) {
//...
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I'm curious though, because I `use` my `ServicesBuilder` the exact same way. What's the problem here? Edit: I missed the `Exceptions` directory.

Comment: It's like as if the ServiceException is in a different folder than you're current one and the interpreter can't find it. You could still have `catch (ServiceException $e)` work but you have to declare a use statement like so: `use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException;`

You probably have a use statement for ServiceBuilder (`use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServicesBuilder;`) at the top of your file.